# What is the probability of randomly chosen real number is even?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I read in the book *A First Course in Probability* by Sheldon Ross the following statement:

> **Technical Remark.** We have supposed that $P(E)$ is defined for all the events $E$ of the sample space. Actually, when the sample space is an uncountably infinite set, $P(E)$ is defined only for a class of events called measurable. However, this restriction need not concern us as all events of any practical interest are measurable.

The set of Real numbers is an infinitely uncountable set then how can we calculate the probability of even real number?

Comment: What is an "even" real number? For example, is $\pi$ even? I think before you address the technical definition of "measurable" (which often requires a full course in its own right), you should clarify your definition of "even".

Comment: @rubikscube09 a real number is even iff it is an element of $2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Ok, now that we have that, what is the probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: That's my doubt @rubikcube09 how do we measure probability on $\mathbb{R}$ as it is not a countable set.

Comment: Not every set is a probability space.  In addition to specifying the elements of the set, you have to explain which subsets are events, and what their probabilities are.  Until you have done this, you can't meaningfully talk about "random" events, so your question, unfortunately, is not meaningful.

Comment: This is the right answer @saulspatz . I doubt why everyone was answering it unnecessarily. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score -1):

The answer is that there is $0$ chance that a randomly chosen number is even, because the set of real numbers is much larger than the set of even numbers (a bigger type of infinity, to be precise).

Comment: How can we say the statement that set of even numbers is less than set of real numbers. Can you explain me mathematically?

Comment: If I choose the random real number equal to $2$ with probabilty $1/2$ and $4$ with probabilty $1/2$ (i.e., $P$ is an atomic measure supported at $2$ and $4$), then $P(\text{even}) = 1$. What does "randomly chosen" mean for a real number?

Comment: randomly chosen here means that the number can be any real number.

Comment: No, that doesn't make any sense. Random here means chosen according to some probability distribution. You can't choose a uniform distribution here; the probability of the total space would not be $1$. The point is that there isn't _the_ probability measure on the real line; there are quite a few measures $P$, but there isn't a canonical choice like Lebesgue measure on an interval.

Answer (score -2):

This gets into a branch of math called measure theory. The idea is, given a set of real numbers, can we give certain measure to it? Probably the most common measure (as far as I know), is Lebesgue measure. It extends the idea of lengths of intervals. For example, any interval $[a,b]$, has measure $b-a$. This is simple enough, but more complicated sets are more complicated to measure. Some sets can not be measured. In a Probability space $S$,  we can then say the probability of an event $E$ is $\frac{\mu(E)}{\mu(S}$. Here $\mu$ is the measure function. It turns out in this case $\mu(E) = 0$ and $\mu(S) = \infty$, so the probability is 0.

If you want to see better why this works, the basic requirements of a measure are

1. Non-negativity: For all E $\mu(E) \ge 0$.
2. Null Empty Set: $\mu(\emptyset) =0$.
3. Countable Additivity: For a countable collection of pairwise disjoint sets $\{E_i\}$, $\mu(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} E_{i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_i)$.

The measure of any point is $0$, as as the integers are a countable collection of points, their measure is the sum of a bunch of zeros, and so is zero.

We can write the reals as an infinite union of intervals of length one, and thus the reals have measure $\infty$.

If you want a more detailed explanation of measure the wikepedia page does a pretty good job explaining it, and it is short. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics).

Comment: Can you explain it elaborately. I didn't get it ?

Comment: Lebesgue measure is not a probability measure on all of $\mathbb{R}$, which has to integrate to 1. You probably have to take a limiting process of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} [-n,n]$.

Comment: @twnly That makes sense, I don't know a lot about the difference between probability measures and a generic measure, I was just thinking about this using a generic measure. If you have more insightful thoughts about how to apply a probability measure in this situation I'd love to hear it!

Comment: $(\mathbb{R}, \mu)$ is not a probability space; it doesn't make sense to say that the probability is $0$. The best you can do is @twnly's suggestion of a limit on spaces $[-n, n]\uparrow \mathbb{R}$, but that requires even more technical details to make rigorous.

Comment: But in reality, I think that if I gather 1000 people and ask each to pick any number, I have a feeling that at least 1 of them will come up with an even number!

Comment: @NoChance You're probably right, but that is because people wouldn't pick numbers randomly. I would guess the large majority would pick integers.